# Cannot find root device when loading a new kernel image

Tags: linux, grub, linux-kernel, grub2

I am trying to install an old linux kernel image 2.6.32.69 just for learning purposes. The machine is ubuntu 15.10 32 bit. The commands to build kernel are:

```
make oldconfig
make bzImage
make modules
sudo make modules_install
```

After this I get a `bzImage` under arch/i386/boot and a `System.map`. I rename bzImage to vmlinuz-2.6.32-69-generic and move to /boot/. Then rename System.map to System.map-2.6.32-69-generic and move to /boot/. Then I add an entry in /boot/grub/grub.cfg by copying an existing entry and made some modifications:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-69-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-2.6.32-69-generic-advanced-20b066c2-67ba-4e36-82d6-6cdd552c4be7' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos1'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  20b066c2-67ba-4e36-82d6-6cdd552c4be7
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 20b066c2-67ba-4e36-82d6-6cdd552c4be7
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.32-69-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-69-generic root=UUID=20b066c2-67ba-4e36-82d6-6cdd552c4be7 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-18-generic
        }
```

However when I restart and choose the newly inserted entry I got:
[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get the config file for the kernel?

Comment: @Paul Type make oldconfig and all choose default. (continue pressing enter) Not sure if it is the same as make defconfig.

Comment: `make oldconfig` uses an existing config file, then asks you for any clarifications for new options that the new kernel may support.  I am asking where the config file came from in the first place - did you use one that was already working?

Comment: @Paul No I didn't. I just uncompress the folder and type make oldconfig. Then it ask me to choose a lot of configurations. Then I just kept hitting enter. Then it generates a .config file.

Comment: The problem may stem from using an initrd from a different kernel version.  The initrd will load the modules needed to get the disks visible to the kernel.  Either this didn't happen, or the symlinks for the UUIDs aren't there.  If `ls -l /dev/[hs]da*` doesn't give you anything, then you'll need to rebuild the initrd.

Comment: why didn't you **sudo make install**?

Comment: @cybernard  I tried that it gives me the same error. I also run sudo initramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32.69 2.6.32.69 after sudo make modules_install. It also give the same error.

Comment: @Paul I tried creating a new initrd by running sudo initramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32.69 2.6.32.69 after sudo make modules_install   but I saw the same error screen. And yes ls -l /dev/[hs]da* doesn't show anything

Comment: You need to use the /dev/sda1 reference not the /dev/disk/by-uuid...  thing.  That version is really quite old, and it there could be additional difficulties.

Comment: @cybernard When I create the initrd.img I saw this: E: intel-microcode: unsupported kernel version! But the initrd.img file is generated.